# Laravel 5.5 Mail causing 404

Tags: laravel-5.5

```
$email = new NewUserVerification(new User([
'email_token' => $user->email_token, 
'name' => $user->email
]));
\Mail::to($user->email)->send($email);
```

I have the above code. Works perfectly on dev machine. When uploaded to server both controllers where NewUserVerification is called get a 404 error. Removing those 2 lines everything works.

I would have assumed its mail configuration, that would be logical, but all other mails are working int he server. Mail provider is mailgun, and I am using the same provider from dev machine and production.

Also, I confirmed the $user object exists.

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: php artisan cache:clear, yes

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but when I moved the email to a queue it worked.